# Why is Bing Maps 7 AJAX control not lazy-loading?

Tags: javascript, ajax, lazy-loading, bing-maps, bing

I'm trying to use Bing Maps 7.0 API with Lazy Loading, as this seem to be supported with the onScriptLoad parameter. I used this minimal test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Bing Maps Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='mapDiv' style="position:absolute; width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initMap() {
            console.log('Callback called');
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {credentials:"<API KEY>"});
        }

        function loadMapControl() 
        {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("src", "http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&onScriptLoad=initMap");
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
            console.log('Tag appened');
        }
        setTimeout(loadMapControl, 1000);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The callback is called as expected, but Firebug throws me an `Microsoft.Maps.Map is not a constructor` error. This even if I delay the map creation by 10 seconds after the callback is called via setTimeout.

The simple example in Bing docs, however, is working perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Bing Maps Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='mapDiv' style="position:absolute; width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {credentials:",API KEY>"});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody succeeded in getting the API 7.0 to work with lazy loading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, this issue has finally been fixed in the newest release of the Maps API.
Everything is working as expected with this new version.

Comment: Great :) Now, if only they could add the other features back, I could finally get rid of 6.3 in customer projects too